# Taylor series of complex function confusion with big O notation

Tags: complex-analysis, notation, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

Suppose $u(x,t)$ is a function of two real numbers that outputs a complex number.

Usually I would have $u(x,t+k) = u(x,t) + k\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t) + \frac{1}{2}k^2 \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial t^2}(x,t) + O(k^3)$

But now that doesn't seem entirely accurate, since $O(k^3)$ is always real (right?). So what would be the correct notation in this case?

More specifically, I'm interested in evaluating the expressions:

$\frac{u(x, t+k) - u(x,t)}{k}$, and $\frac{u(x-h, t) -2u(x,t) + u(x+h, t)}{h^2}$

In the real case, I'd say that

$\frac{u(x, t+k) - u(x,t)}{k} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t) + O(k)$ and $\frac{u(x-h, t) -2u(x,t) + u(x+h, t)}{h^2} = \frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x^2}(x,t) + O(h^2)$

What is the complex equivalent? Is this notation also correct in the complex sense?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Just remember that distances on the complex plane are measured by the absolute value. The fact that it gives a complex number does not change anything. By the way, is your function analytic?

Comment: On a second reading it seems that your problem might be a misunderstanding of the big O notation. I suggest you look up the definition.

Comment: Using big-O notation is fine in the complex case, and I see it done all the time. You perhaps have to be a bit more careful about what it formally means, but it is quite useful in complex analysis since that is where Taylor Series live.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use the following definition:

for a function $f$ defined in a neighbourhood of $0$ and a non-negative function $g$ defined at least on the same neighbourhood, we say that $f(z) = O(g(z))$ if there exist $r>0$ and $M>0$ such that for all $z$ with $|z|<r$ it holds that $|f(z)|\le M\cdot g(z)$.

Theis definition works whether we are talking about real or complex functions. You just have to make sure that the functions you are talking about is Lipschitz continuously differentiable enough times in the variable that you care.